# Get a valid match for a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Hej,

I'm doing a project which involves a quiz. Multiple choice and text input as answers.
For checking the text input answers there is a RegEx. For instance:

What is the name of this operation: 3 + 5.
Possible answers: Addition, addition, Plus, plus, Sum, sum, +
RegEx: `/^((A|a)ddition|(P|p)lus|(S|s)um|\+)$/`

So far so good. But now I want to display a valid answer if someone answers incorrectly. I don't want to redundantly save this in the database.

So my question is: Is there a php-function that gives me a valid string for any given RegEx?

Like: `echo 'Your answer is wrong, '.valid_pattern($theRegEx).' would have been better.';`

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you want is to generate result data using a regex as seed?

Comment: i think you're better off storing all possible answers in an  an array (combine this with foreach and stripos) and then popping off an element when you need an example (as opposed to trying to do a reverse regex)

Comment: If you're going to do this with a regular expression then consider accepting different casing for every letter in each word, not just the first letter. Then you can save yourself some hassle and use the case-insensitive flag, `i` e.g. `/^(addition|plus|sum|\+)$/i`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate sample data using a regex you can check at `ReverseRegex` php project.

https://github.com/icomefromthenet/ReverseRegex

Here you have an example form its page:

```
use ReverseRegex\Lexer;
use ReverseRegex\Random\SimpleRandom;
use ReverseRegex\Parser;
use ReverseRegex\Generator\Scope;

# load composer
require "vendor/autoload.php";

$lexer = new  Lexer('[a-z]{10}');
$gen   = new SimpleRandom(10007);
$result = '';

$parser = new Parser($lexer,new Scope(),new Scope());
$parser->parse()->getResult()->generate($result,$gen);

echo $result;
```

Will generate:

```
jmceohykoa
aclohnotga
jqegzuklcv
ixdbpbgpkl
kcyrxqqfyw
jcxsjrtrqb
kvaczmawlz
itwrowxfxh
auinmymonl
dujyzuhoag
vaygybwkfm
```

I haven't tried it but I think it is useful for your need.